# Can crypto locker spread to other attached media?

Tags: virus

My sister just got her computer infected with the wonderful crypto locker. She also has a memory card with important photos on them, that "may or may not have been plugged into the computer", when she got this virus. I was going to at least look and see if the card is encrypted, but I'm very weary of this. I know that the virus will encrypt any attached local media. But is it possible for the virus itself to spread to those devices? If I plug this memory card into another computer, will it infect that computer?

Comment: The only way the virus will spread is if the memory card has been infected with an autorun of some sort and the virus code in the form of an exe or other executable file... Personally iw ould investigate the memory stick using a LiveCd such as Ubuntu - these run but the platform is incompatible with Windows executables (that the crypto usually comes as) so they can be a very good method of safely checking a disk. Also, to be extra safe, disconnect her already infected HDD and other "writeable" media.

Comment: CryptoLocker will encrypt any volume it can access.